# Controlling how a date-time object is printed without coercing to a character?

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format

Imagine I have a data frame in which some columns represent dates or times.  When working with these columns, it is convenient to have them formatted as `POSIXlt` objects (or other explicitly date/time oriented class).

However, when I display these columns to the screen or print them out to a .csv, I get the full ISO8601 formatted time. I realize I can turn the times into a character vector formatted however I desire using `format(col, format="%m-%Y")` or whatever I have in mind, but I'm not keen on changing the class of my object just to print.  Other objects in R have print methods associated with them, we don't have to explicitly coerce them. Is there some way to do that with any of the date time classes of R objects that I've overlooked?

EDIT:

Here's a minimal example of what I'd hope to achieve:

```
a.datetime = Sys.time()
a.datetime
```

Displays:

```
2014-06-23 09:32:12
```

which is the format I get out in the CSV

```
write.csv(data.frame(a.datetime), "example.csv")
```

As I describe above, I realize I can coerce this to a character with the desired format manually, e.g.:

format(a.datetime, format="%y-%m")
   write.csv(data.frame(format(a.datetime, format="%y-%m")), "example.csv")

Which is not what I want to have to do; I am looking for a way for the object to know how it should be printed without the user having to both apply that formatting and coerce to a character vector as shown above.  (Hopefully this clarifies what I mean by changing type, I am referring the class of the output, not the class of the argument).

I can try to define such a class as below, e.g. using S3 classes, but it still does not print to csv using the format specified.

```
class(a.datetime) <- c("myclass", class(a.datetime))
attr(a.datetime, 'fmt') <- "%y-%m"
print.myclass <- function(x) print(format(x, format=attr(x,"fmt")))
print.csv(data.frame(a.datetime), "temp.csv")
```

Still prints a csv with the full ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Perhaps you could post `dput(head())` of your data so we see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: Your understanding of datetime objects is flawed. Using format(.) does _not_ change the arguments given to it. POSIXct vectors are just doubles with attributes, while POSIXlt objects are lists of integer values, so you _will_ need to use a function to translate to a human readable form regardless of which class you use. POSIXlt objects are problematic to store in dataframes so it is very much preferred to keep datatimes in POSIXct. Display to the screen is mediate by `print.POSIXt`.

Comment: are you mainly interested in formatting for inspection during debugging, or final output / conversion?  It makes a difference.

Comment: @BondedDust Sorry if I was unclear, but I never suggested that it changed the argument.  I'm referring to how it prints to a csv file.

Comment: If you want to output to a csv file, then what other version of a datetime object _do_ you want?  You could, of course, use `as.numeric` to convert to seconds from an origin. If you want object that are intrinsically year-month, then look at the zoo package's yearmon-class.

Comment: I don't want a class limited to a specific format (I just use %y-%m as an example).  I am looking for an object that can take any format, just like POSIXlt class does, and remember the choice when printing to a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty annoying that the base R functions for writing data don't have an argument to let the user easily adjust the datetime format.

There are ways around it, though.  Here's what I've done sometimes when I want to specify a format quickly and I don't need to worry about side effects:

```sh
# In bash
Rscript -e "x <- readRDS('foo.rds'); "\
        -e "as.character.POSIXct <- function(x) format(x, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'); " \
        -e "write.csv(x, 'foo.csv', row.names=FALSE)"
```

(I'm showing that in a shell command just to emphasize that you'll want the new `as.character.POSIXct` method to disappear after using it.)

The essence is overriding the `as.character` method for the `POSIXct` class (for arcane reasons, overriding for the parent `POSIXt` class won't work):

```
as.character.POSIXct <- function(x)
  format(x, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

It's not something that should be done in a larger codebase where the global effects might spill into code that's not expecting it, though!

Answer (score 0):

Some code to expand on my comment. R is a functional language so operations on a vector (and lists are actually vectors) will not change the vector, but will return a processed result and in the case of datatime objects that us usually a character vector. Here's a few views of a POSIXlt object:

```
x <- as.POSIXlt("2000-01-01")
x
#[1] "2000-01-01 PST"
x <- as.POSIXlt("2000-01-01 12:00:00")
x
#[1] "2000-01-01 12:00:00 PST"
 str(x)
# POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2000-01-01 12:00:00"
 mode(x)
#[1] "list"
 x[[1]]
#[1] 0
 x[[2]]
#[1] 0
 x[[3]]
#[1] 12
 x[[4]]
#[1] 1


 unlist(x)
#   sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst   zone gmtoff 
#   "0"    "0"   "12"    "1"    "0"  "100"    "6"    "0"    "0"  "PST"     NA 
 mode(x[[3]])
#[1] "numeric"
# x[[10]]; mode(x[[10]])
#[1] "PST"
#[1] "character"
```

Notice that the `unlist()` process converted the list to a character vector. In R only lists can have mixed modes so the single character element in a `POSIXlt` object will end up coercing all of the elements that were stored as numeric values to character elements. As noted above POSIXlt object are tricky to use and the dataframe functions generally do not behave well with them because most (well-behaved) dataframe columns are atomic vectors rather than lists.

Comment: I am fully aware that the class of the object is not changed. Note that I specifically am referring to how the object prints, e.g. in print.csv or printing to terminal.